# R placing bars arbitrarly in barplot

Tags: r

I have following problem that I have to place the bars at dedicated x-values.
I have a series, say of a frequency (say from 0 to 100) where i want to show the values for dedicated frequencies.
For example:

```
width : 1 1 3 2 4
height: 6 2 1 5 4
```

x-frequency for example: 1,2,3 6,12 is where to plot the bars

when i do the barplot:
     barplot(width, height)
     axis(1,,seq(0,15,1))

i get the following:

[image]

But that is not what i want, i want the bars at locations according to my values  1,2,3 6,12

Answer (score 0):

I´ve found a solution: since barplot does the positioning, i would have to do it another way, i can place a bar with the "rect" command:
    rect(xleft=3, ybottom=0, xright=5, ytop=6)

[image]

This is exactly what i wanted.